# Calculating n-digit palindromes infinite loop

Tags: math, recursion, racket

I am trying to go through SICP using Racket and Project Euler as reference for practice. This question is in regards to problem 4 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=4), hence:

*A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.*

I am currently still on Chapter 1 (SICP) and loops have not been covered yet, as I see most solutions use. My code runs out of memory every time I try to execute (I have been stuck on this for hours - https://github.com/polila/Project-Euler/commits?author=polila&since=2018-03-19T04:00:00Z&until=2018-03-20T04:00:00Z) LOL.

What I am trying to do is use a recursive procedure by the process of linear iteration (at least that's what I think) - so in my mind it was something like this, where a and b are the max limit of n-digit:

```
(largest-palindrome a   b   max)
(                  999  999   0)
(                  999  998   0)
(                  999  997   0)
(                   .   .     .)
(                   .   .     .)
(                  999  99    x)
(                  998  998   x)
(                  998  997   x)
(                  998  996   x)
(                  .    .     x)
(                  100  100   x)
```

I realize that I wouldn't have to go all the way to the minimum range but even for small test cases such as 2-digit palindromes with the range of [90,99] it still doesn't execute. But here is my code, where am I going wrong??????????

```
#lang racket

(define (exp a b)
    (define (iter product count)
      (if (= count b)
          product
          (iter (* a product) (+ count 1))))
  (if (= b 0)
      1
      (iter a 1)))

(define (palindrome? ab)
  (define (length ab)
    (define (iter n count)
      (if (= n 0)
          count
          (iter (floor (/ n 10)) (+ count 1))))
    (iter ab 0))
    (define (check-symmetry ab left right)
          (if (> left right)
              (if (= (floor (/ (modulo ab (exp 10 left)) (exp 10 (- left 1))))
                     (floor (/ (modulo ab (exp 10 right)) (exp 10 (- right 1)))))
                  (check-symmetry ab (- left 1) (+ right 1))
                  #f)
              #t))
        (check-symmetry ab (length ab) 1))

(define (largest-palindrome a b max)
 (if (> b 100)
     (if (and (palindrome? (* a b)) (< max (* a b)))
         (largest-palindrome a (- b 1) (* a b))
         (largest-palindrome a (- b 1) max))
     (largest-palindrome (- a 1) (- a 1) (* a b)))
  (if (< a 100)
      max
      0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right general idea of looking at multiples starting at 999x999 all the way down to 100x100. You can improve efficiency on this method by terminating `b` whenever `a x b` is a palindrome, such that you don't test for palindromes in `a x b-1` etc. since those products will be smaller in value than `a x b`.

What this looks like is:

```
999 x 999            -- not palindrome
999 x 998            -- not palindrome
    |
995 x 583            -- palindrome (if current palindrome < this, save this value)
994 x 994            -- not palindrome (Notice the jump here instead of testing 995 x 582)
994 x 993            -- not palindrome
    |
994 x 100            -- not palindrome
993 x 993            -- not palindrome
    |
993 x 913            -- palindrome (if current < this, save this value)
992 x 992            -- not palindrome
    |
100 x 100            -- not palindrome (hit base case and return current palindrome)
```

In your implementation of `largest-palindrome`, the first if-statement, ie. `(if (> b 100) ...)`, is dead code. Moreover, the recursive steps in that if statement also have no base case(s), hence why you run out of memory every time as a result of the infinite recursion.

You can simplify much of your code. For example, consider the following `palindrome?` predicate that checks whether a number is equal to its digits reversed:

```
(define (palindrome? n)
  (define (in-reverse n acc)
    (if (< n 10)
        (+ (* acc 10) n)
        (in-reverse (quotient n 10)
                    (+ (* acc 10)
                       (remainder n 10)))))
  (= n (in-reverse n 0)))
```

ie.

```
(palindrome? 1001)
=> #t
(palindrome? 1010)
=> #f
```

You can then implement `largest-palindrome` using this predicate:

```
;; largest-palindrome: Finds the largest palindrome that is a
;; multiple of two numbers, each of which has n digits.
(define (largest-palindrome n)
  (define low (expt 10 (sub1 n)))     ;; if n = 3, low  = 100
  (define high (sub1 (expt 10 n)))    ;; if n = 3, high = 999
  (define (largest a b mymax low high)
    (define prod (* a b))
    (cond
      ((< a low) mymax)
      ((or (< b low)
           (< prod mymax))
       (largest (sub1 a) (sub1 high) mymax low (sub1 high)))
      ((and (> prod mymax)
            (palindrome? prod))
       (largest (sub1 a) (sub1 high) prod b (sub1 high)))
      (else
       (largest a (sub1 b) mymax low high))))
  (largest high high 0 low high))
```

this works for various values of `n`:

```
(largest-palindrome 3)
=> 906609
(largest-palindrome 5)
=> 9966006699
(largest-palindrome 7)
=> 99956644665999
```